# React Hook setState function not updating value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to put together a MERN stack application and I am currently working on the client-side. React hooks are somewhat new to me and I am currently trying to use them using `usePopup` from the react-hook-popup library class, but the values won't update and I'm not sure why?

The two lines of relevant code from below I am particularly having trouble updating are:

```
const [newChore, setNewChore] = useState("")
const [newChoreIndex, setNewChoreIndex] = useState(-1)
```

EDIT1: So I have noticed if I setState outside of the popup hook, state will update, which I do for the 'newChoreIndex' hook. Is there something I need to be able to use these hook variables with the popup?

EDIT2: I have repo's to both client-side and server-side which I can share if that makes things easier. After cloning, just run npm i, and then npm start for both applications.

server-side: https://github.com/halsheik/HouseholdHomiesBackend.git
client-side: https://github.com/halsheik/HouseholdHomiesFrontend.git

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { usePopup } from 'react-hook-popup';
import Axios from "axios";
import "../../stylesheets/modal.css";
import "../../stylesheets/homepage.css";

function HomePage() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [group, setGroup] = useState(null);
    const [newChore, setNewChore] = useState("")
    const [newChoreIndex, setNewChoreIndex] = useState(-1)
    const [showPopup, hidePopup] = usePopup('popup', ({ message, handleClose }) => (
        <div className="modal">
            <div className="modalInner">
                <button 
                    className="modalClose"
                    onClick={handleClose}>
                    X
                </button>

                <div className="modalInner2">
                    <p className="modalHeading">Previous Chore(s)</p>
                    <p className="modalChore">{message}</p>

                    <p className="modalHeading">New Chore {newChoreIndex}</p>
                    <input
                        className="newChoreInput"
                        placeholder="New Chore"
                        onChange={(e) => {setNewChore(e.target.value)}}
                    />

                    <button 
                        className="modalSubmit"
                        onClick={() => {
                            updateChore()
                            hidePopup()
                        }}>
                        Update Chore
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ));

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios({
            method: "GET",
            withCredentials: true,
            url: "http://localhost:4000/",
        }).then((res) => {
            setUser(res.data);
            
            if(!res.data) {
                window.location.href = "/login"; 
            }
        });

        Axios({
            method: "GET",
            withCredentials: true,
            url: "http://localhost:4000/group",
        }).then((res) => {
            setGroup(res.data);
            console.log(res);
        });
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(newChore)
    }, [newChore])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(newChoreIndex)
    }, [newChoreIndex])

    const updateChore = () => {
        
    };

    return (
        <div className="mainContainer">
            {user ? (

            <div className="contentContainer">
                <p className="homepageHeading">Welcome resident's of {user.address}</p>
                
                {!group ? (
                <div className="groupNotSetupContainer">
                    <p className="groupNotSetup">Household has not been setup</p>
                    <a href="/createGroup" className="groupNotSetupButtonContainer"><button className="groupNotSetupButton">Setup Household</button></a>
                </div>

                ) : (

                <div className="groupContent">
                    <div className="groupContentCol">
                        <p className="groupContentColHeading">Household Members</p>

                        {group.members.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={index} className="groupContentColMember">
                                        <p className="groupContentColItemText">{item["name"]}</p>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            }
                        )}
                    </div>

                    <div className="groupContentCol">
                        <p className="groupContentColHeading">Chores</p>

                        {group.chores.map((item, index) => {
                                var member = group.head + parseInt(index)

                                if(member >= group.members.length) {
                                    member = 0
                                }

                                return (
                                    <div key={index} className="groupContentColChore">
                                        {item === "organizer" ? (
                                        <div className="groupContentColChoreInner">
                                            <p className="groupContentColItemText">{item}</p>
                                            <p className="groupContentColItemText assignedChore">{group.members[member]["name"]}</p>
                                        </div>
                                        ) : (
                                        <div className="groupContentColChoreInner">
                                            <p className="groupContentColItemText killCurves">{item}</p>
                                            <p className="groupContentColItemText assignedChore">{group.members[member]["name"]}</p>
                                        </div>)}
                                        
                                        {item !== "organizer" && <p 
                                            href="#"
                                            className="groupContentColChoreEdit"
                                            onClick={() => {
                                                setNewChoreIndex(index)
                                                showPopup(item)
                                            }}>Edit</p>
                                        }
                                        
                                    </div>
                                )
                            }
                        )}
                    </div>
                </div>
                

                )}
                </div>
            
            ) : (
            // should not enter here
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome to household homies, please login</h1>
                <p><a href="/login">login</a></p>
                <p><a href="/register">register</a></p>
            </div>

            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default HomePage;
```

[image]

EDIT 4:

Popup hook

```
const [showPopup, hidePopup] = usePopup('popup', ({ message, chore, handleClose }) => (
        <div className="modal">
            <div className="modalInner">
                <button 
                    className="modalClose"
                    onClick={handleClose}>
                    X
                </button>

                <div className="modalInner2">
                    <p className="modalHeading">Previous Chore(s)</p>
                    <p className="modalChore">{message}</p>

                    <p className="modalHeading">New Chore {chore}</p>
                    <input
                        className="newChoreInput"
                        placeholder="New Chore"
                        onChange={(e) => {setNewChore(e.target.value)}}
                    />

                    <button 
                        className="modalSubmit"
                        onClick={() => {
                            console.log(chore)
                            updateChore()
                            hidePopup()
                        }}>
                        Update Chore
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ));
```

hook call

```
showPopup(item, newChore)
```

EDIT 5:

Before clicking 'edit' to open popup:
[image]

After opening popup (notice a blank and -1 in the console indicating the newChore and newChoreIndex passed in)

[image]

After typing in input field of popup (notice the console with 5 blanks since I console.logged the newChore value in the popup which still has no value)

[image]

After closing the popup and reopening (notice the values of newChore and newChoreIndex have updated)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I can't comment because I've only just made an account**

That being said I can update this answer if you can provide a bit more information :)

Where are you checking for the result of the new chore being set? I can see in the code you posted that there's the new chore index being logged in the `updateChore` function but not the `newChore` itself. Have you tried logging in another `useEffect`? like...

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(newChore);
}, [newChore]);
```

* **UPDATE**

Seeing as you're only using `newChore` inside the popup, you could try moving the `useState` call for `newChore` inside of the popup body then passing it to the `updateChore` function like this

```
const [showPopup, hidePopup] = usePopup('popup', ({ message, handleClose }) => {
  const [newChore, setNewChore] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(newChore);
  }, [newChore]);

  return (
    <div className="modal">
        <div className="modalInner">
            <button 
                className="modalClose"
                onClick={handleClose}>
                X
            </button>

            <div className="modalInner2">
                <p className="modalHeading">Previous Chore(s)</p>
                <p className="modalChore">{message}</p>

                <p className="modalHeading">New Chore {newChoreIndex}</p>
                <input
                    className="newChoreInput"
                    placeholder="New Chore"
                    onChange={(e) => {setNewChore(e.target.value)}}
                />

                <button 
                    className="modalSubmit"
                    onClick={() => {
                        updateChore(newChore)
                        hidePopup()
                    }}>
                    Update Chore
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
});
```

This will stop the `useEffect` on `setChore` working outside of the popup though as it's not in scope, so you'll probably have to move that into the popup as well to see if it's updating on change.

Comment: I'm personally not too familiar with useEffect and am slowly learning as I go, but I will definitely give that a try now! And as for more information, what information do you need me to provide?

Comment: I missed your question. I check for the result of newChore being set in the newChore variable itself. I just console.log the variable to see what's stored in it, but it does not seem to update when I use setNewChore(e.target.value) (this isn't shown in the code but I do it in the popup). As for the chore index variable, I've attempted console.logging it outside the popup hook, and it seems to update and display the correct value, but if I do it from in the popup hook, whether directly or through a function (i.e. updateChore), it retains a value of -1.

Comment: No problem :) Where are you logging the `newChore` variable out? Does the the component re-render when you type something in to the input? Like, if you log anything like `console.log('render')` in the body of the component function then type in the input does that log show?

Comment: I am logging newChore in the onChange of the input with the class "newChoreInput". When I type something in the input, the console seems to print nothing but with a counter to the side indicating it reprinted to console. I'm not sure how to determine if the component rerendered?

Comment: I do believe it re-renders because the console displays prints the console.log that's within the useEffect. I have added the newChore value in the brackets of the useEffect as u have shown me.

Comment: I added updates above. I've noticed that as my code is above, newChore and newChoreIndex seem to update properly, however, if I try to access the values inside the popup hook, they seem to still have their original value. I'm not sure why that is?

Comment: The log won't change (as far as I'm aware) in the `onChange`. From what I understand when you call `setNewChore` react will queue or store that change, run everything else that comes after then re-render the component as the data has changed. When the component re-renders it runs the function component again, so the `useState` function will be called again and return the updated value for `newChore`.

If you `console.log(newChore)` somewhere else in the component body it should in theory log when the value changes :)

* Sorry took too long to respond and you'd already replied

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to access the new values within the popup hook? And the explanation helped me understand how it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Try passing the values into `showPopup` like `showPopup({ newChore, newChoreIndex })` then accessing them as `message.newChore` and `message.newChoreIndex`

Comment: Also, no problem man :)

Comment: I added an edit at the bottom showing I implemented your suggestion and it does not seem to work. Did I write it properly? Also, message contains a dynamic value which is passed in, wouldn't it not have member variables?

Comment: Nevermind!!! I just passed in the value as a dictionary from the call. Thank you so much!!1

Comment: I'd assume you'd be able to use an object as that dynamic value if it only takes the one value as an argument? If you're already passing in `item`, could you not pass in an object like `{ item, newChore }` then use `{ message.item }` where you're already using `{ message }`?

Comment: Ah good man :) sorry it's taking me too long to reply to these bahaha

Comment: Thats ok! I might just not be refreshing page on time either haha. I have one more questions, lets say I want the updateChore function to display the correct newChore and newChoreIndex values (the function currently just logs the values and it displays what was previously stored in the newChore and newChoreIndex values). How can I make it display the changes upon that function call?

Comment: Is the value in the `updateChore` function missing the last update, like the last character or whatever? You could pass the values as arguments into the `updateChore` function if they're correct in the popup when the function is called :)

Comment: So, the popup hook itself only has the value of newChore and newChoreIndex that it gets passed. Since these values are passed in, they aren't updated until the popup is reopened, therefore, if a newChore is inputted in that popup, the value of newChore in that popup is not update until the popup is closed and reopened. Ill add screenshots so its easier to visualize.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with another suggestion :)

Comment: So adding the hook for newChore inside popup throws the following error: "React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks". The same error is also thrown for the call to useEffect.

Comment: So I actually resolved me issue by removing the two hooks, creating a variable for the newChore in the popup, and passing in the index value. Pretty much modified code using different parts of ur suggestions! Thank you.

Comment: Ah sound man no problem :) glad you got it sorted.